# Heroku Version: error getting commands pid ..... SIGSEGV (signal 11)

Tags: heroku

I've installed the heroku toolbelt for windows (windows 10).
When I run the command heroku version I keep getting this error message.
I uninstalled heroku and reinstalled it without luck.
Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Norton antivirus, or Norton 360 in my case, quarantines heroku-cli.exe because it says it is behaving badly.  Try restoring it from quarantine and telling Norton to leave it alone.  I have to do this periodically, such as when Heroku Toolbelt is upgraded, even when that is done dynamically just by using the Heroku command.